# Cannot reinitialise DataTable with Angular Datatable

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript, datatable

I have a Angular application with a simple CRUD functionality. I have tested my data with a static HTML table and this works. Now I am using a data table framework called Angular data table.

Link: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

I can **Create**, **Read** and **Delete** a record but after this action I get a error like:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

I have tried several solutions like the link it provided and other stack overflows post like this:

[Getting error in Angular 5 Datatables: cannot reinitialise DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232450/getting-error-in-angular-5-datatables-cannot-reinitialise-datatable)

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

This is my code in **car-component.js** and I use a **car-services.js** for all my HTTP calls.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CarService } from '../services/carservices/car.service';
import { CarVM } from '../viewmodels/car/car-vm';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car',
  templateUrl: './car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car.component.css']
})
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

  FormCar: any;
  countrecords: any;
  Carid: number = 0;
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  allCars: CarVM[];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private carservice: CarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
    };

    this.GetCar();
    this.GetCarCount();

    this.FormCar = this.formbuilder.group({
      CarId: ['', Validators.required],
      Brand: ['', Validators.required],
      Model: ['', Validators.required],
      Color: ['', Validators.required],
      TopSpeed: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  AddCar(CarVM: CarVM) {
    CarVM.CarId = this.Carid;
    this.carservice.CreateCar(CarVM).subscribe(() => {
      this.GetCar();
      this.GetCarCount();
      this.Reset();
      this.Carid = 0;
    })
  }

  GetCar() {
    this.carservice.getAllCars().subscribe(res => {
      this.allCars = res;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    })
  }

  GetCarCount() {
    this.countrecords = this.carservice.getCount();
  }

  EditCar(car: CarVM) {
    this.carservice.updateCar(car).subscribe(Response => {
      this.Carid = Response.CarId;
      this.FormCar.controls['Brand'].setValue(Response.Brand);
      this.FormCar.controls['Model'].setValue(Response.Model);
      this.FormCar.controls['Color'].setValue(Response.Color);
      this.FormCar.controls['TopSpeed'].setValue(Response.TopSpeed);
    })
  }

  DeleteCar(CarId: string) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      this.carservice.deleteCar(CarId).subscribe(() => {
        this.GetCar();
        this.GetCarCount();
      })
    }
  }

  Reset() {
    this.FormCar.reset();
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML page from car:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Speed</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let car of allCars">
      <td>{{car.carId}}</td>
      <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
      <td>{{car.model}}</td>
      <td>{{car.color}}</td>
      <td>{{car.topSpeed }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-1" (click)="DeleteCar(car.carId)">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

NOTE:

I used the **Angular** version not the **JQuery** version!

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

You need to **destroy** datatable instance before triggering it again.

You can create a function like this:

`import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';`

`dtElement: DataTableDirective;`

`isDtInitialized:boolean = false`

```
  GetCar() {
    this.carservice.getAllCars().subscribe(res => {
      this.allCars = res;

      if (this.isDtInitialized) {
        this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
          dtInstance.destroy();
          this.dtTrigger.next();
        });
      } else {
        this.isDtInitialized = true
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      }
    })
  }
```

Using this, for the first time it will go to the else block and trigger datatable directly. After that when you refresh, it will first destroy the datatable and then trigger.

Comment: Thanks for you time! Do I need to call this function in my **constructor**?

Comment: Edited the answer, do it in getCar()

Comment: I initialized the Boolean variable and used your method. Then I call it on the **ngOnInit()** **this.getCar();** when I refresh I get the same error instantly. After I click okay my data is loading.

Comment: Please show your function in the comment, or better if you can create a stackbiltz. I had faced the same thing and fixed it by destroying dtInstance

Comment: delete the line ` this.dtTrigger.next();` after the line ` this.allCars = res;`, the 3rd line in GetCar()

Comment: The error is gone when I refresh. I still get the error when I **delete** and **create** a car

Comment: Please update the stackbiltz, It would have been better if stackbiltz demo was working

Comment: I added the  **viewmodel** and **services** I use a .NET core backend for the data.

Comment: App/module isn't correct, dependencies not installed, therefore it is not working in stackbiltz. However the code seems fine

Comment: @AdritaSharma I am getting *ERROR TypeError: "this.dtElement is undefined"* error

Comment: Declare `this.dtElement `. Like this: `import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';`,     `dtElement: DataTableDirective;`.

Comment: I declared like this:  `dtElement: DataTableDirective;` above that is working fine maybe I have to use your if statement in the other methods?

Comment: @Fearcoder That is fine, you can refactor it. I usually create resetdatatable function, and on add, delete iniit, everytime call that function

Comment: **Updated** stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16dxfk I made a function it's working on **getCar** but not on **delete** and **create**

Comment: @Fearcoder I am looking, your stackbiltz isn't working

Comment: Yes I use a .NET core backend application for the data this is my structure

Comment: @AdritaSharma Ihave declared as you said but still got the error

Comment: @AdritaSharma I have posted an question where i have mentioned all.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer @Adrita Sharma was not working for me, it was throwing this error.

> core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dtInstance' of
>   undefined

So I added

```
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective, {static: false})
```

and it worked

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

export class AttendancePage implements OnInit {

@ViewChild(DataTableDirective, {static: false})
dtElement: DataTableDirective;

isDtInitialized:boolean = false;
```

And inside function where i initialized my datatable

```
if (this.isDtInitialized) {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.destroy();
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
} else {
    this.isDtInitialized = true;
    this.dtTrigger.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" 
                                                style="width: 99.5% !important;" class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                <th>Client ID</th>
                                                <th>Client Name</th>
                                                <th>Client Phone</th>
                                                <th>Join Date</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Is Active</th>
                                                <th>Operation</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody *ngIf="modelList && modelList?.length != 0">
                                                <tr *ngFor="let m of modelList">
                                                <td>{{ m.ClientID }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ m.ClientName }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ m.ClientPhone }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ m.JoinDate | date : "MMM d, y" }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ m.Email}}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <div class="btn-group project-list-ad" *ngIf="m.IsActive">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs">Active</button>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="btn-group project-list-ad-rd" *ngIf="!m.IsActive">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-white btn-xs">Unactive</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-pill btn-dark" type="button" (click)='editbuttonClick(m.ClientID)'>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-sm mt-1"></i>&nbsp;Edit
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tbody *ngIf="!modelList || modelList?.length == 0">
                                                <tr>
                                                <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
```

Type Script Code
For Angular 8

```
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective, {static : false})
dtElement: DataTableDirective;

dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
dtTrigger: Subject<ClientList> = new Subject();
```

implements AfterViewInit on classs

```
loadAllData() {

const that = this;


this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    that._http
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        //'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
        this.env.apiUrl + 'api/setup/ClientList_SelectAll_Grid',
        dataTablesParameters, {}
      ).subscribe(resp => {
        //console.log(dataTablesParameters);
        that.modelList = resp.data;


        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: []
        });
      });
  },
  columns: [{ data: 'ClientID' }, { data: 'ClientName' }, { data: 'ClientPhone' }, { data: 'JoinDate' }, { data: 'Email' }, { data: 'IsActive' }, { defaultContent: '', orderable: false }]
};



 }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
 }



 rerender(): void {

this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
  // Destroy the table first
  dtInstance.destroy();
  // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
  this.dtTrigger.next();
});


}
```

[full example of Angular DataTables Server side pagination & Sorting](http://littleprograming.blogspot.com/2019/11/angular-datatables-server-side.html)

Comment: when calling render function, after adding new data , its only showing last added record. Not showing all records. Can you please help ? How can I fix to show all records including newly added record.

--
Thanks

Comment: i got success to fix it. Thanks for reply.