# Angular Datatable: Table data is not updated for every search(once refresh and re-search only getting new data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

Angular Datatable: Have search fields. will do select and will get datatable population. First time working fine, once we click with some other data and click, API response coming but data is not updated in the table. Could you please suggest me how to destroy/reinitialize table for next click. Here is the sample code I written

```
    //html table
    
         <table
            datatable
            [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
            [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
            class="row-border hover">
            </table> 

    //datatable properties

    this.dtOptions = {
          data: jsonData,
          pagingType: "full_numbers",
          pageLength: 10,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          processing: true,
          fixedHeader: true,
          destroy: true,
          columns: [
            {data: 'test1'},
            {data: 'test2'},
            {data: 'test3'},
      ]
    }

 //http.get for response

    this.http
        .get(url, {params})
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.results = res;
          this.dtTrigger.next();
   }
    //Table destroy

     ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
      }
```

Comment: does your ```this.http.get``` is in ngOnInit ?

Comment: No, while click on button I'm calling this.http.get

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is duplicates with

[Getting error in Angular 5 Datatables: cannot reinitialise DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232450/getting-error-in-angular-5-datatables-cannot-reinitialise-datatable)

In order to reinitialize table for next click you can define this

```
rerender(): void {
  this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
     dtInstance.destroy();
     this.dtTrigger.next();     
 });
```

and call **rerender()** function after server response

Hope that answers your question